# What is default MySQL binlog retention in AWS RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-5.6, log

I tried to  retrieve my MySQL RDS binlogs in order to run manual "rollback" for some SQLs.
Unfortunately, I noticed that only 2 binlogs for the last 30 minutes are available.

"call mysql.rds_show_configuration" provides "binlog retention hours | NULL".

I guess (because RDS provides ability to point-in-time restore between daily backups) that AWS RDS keeps its binlogs for 24 hours. But it seems that it's unavailable for the end user...

TIA,
Vitay

Answer (score 9):

You need to give it a value if you wish to preserve the binlogs:

```
call mysql.rds_set_configuration('binlog retention hours', 24);
```

Will cause the binlogs to be stored for 24 hours, for example.

Comment: This needs to be done on Master or Slave ?

Comment: Master.  This tells the master to hold onto the log files for a longer period of time so disconnected or new slaves have more time to connect and catch up

Comment: Changing the value causes downtime?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html#USER_LogAccess.MySQL.Binarylog) says "Amazon RDS normally purges a binary log as soon as possible". That's why Ross's answer says you must set a value. The NULL you saw effectively means 0, and the only reason you'd see a list of results when running `show binary logs` in mysql is that mysql is actively using that log. Unfortunately, I don't know what "actively" means exactly. In my experience they last for a few minutes at most with a continually but minimally used database.