# Is it possible to fetch AWS RDS MySQL transaction logs?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws

I have AWS RDS MySQL instance, without general query logs.
Is it possible to get all transaction logs? I understand that MySQL binlog retention time is very short, but obviously, AWS RDS keeps all transactions for providing point-in-time recovery. So - is/how it possible to fetch this log?

Comment: What will you use the information for?  (As Bill points out, there are different logs for different, though overlapping, purposes.)

Comment: Some tables were modified, we's like to know when - in order to investigate this incident.

Comment: Can you access the binlogs?

Comment: @RickJames Thank you! I know about MySQL binlog, but AFAIK binlog retention period for RDS is very short (dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68272/…). But we're able to use point-in-time recovery for one month, so I guess AWS uses something else

Answer (score 1):

The point-in-time recovery also uses the binary log. To use them for PITR, you must have non-expired binary logs back to the most recent full backup.

You can use [SHOW BINARY LOGS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/show-binary-logs.html) in a query client to view the currently non-expired binary logs. You can use the command-line tool [mysqlbinlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/mysqlbinlog.html) to dump logs from a remote instance (i.e. you could run this on an EC2 instance or another server that was set up to be a client for your RDS instance).

The term "transaction log" in MySQL usually refers to the [InnoDB redo log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-redo-log.html). This is a different log. There's no way to fetch this from a remote client, and there's no tool to use it for PITR anyway.

Fetching the binary logs yourself might not be the solution intended by AWS for PITR of RDS instances. You should review the information they have about backup solutions: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/point-in-time-recovery-and-continuous-backup-for-amazon-rds-with-aws-backup/

Comment: Thank you! I know about MySQL binlog, but AFAIK binlog retention period for RDS is very short (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68272/what-is-default-mysql-binlog-retention-in-aws-rds).
But we're able to use point-in-time recovery for one month, so I guess AWS uses something else.

Comment: I believe they back up the binary logs on some other storage, and let them expire on the RDS instance. That way they can store the bulk of the binlogs on cheaper storage. They don't have to be on your costly provisioned-iops EBS volume after they are done being used for replication.

Answer (score 0):

Run this

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%expire_logs%';
```

Then see if AWS lets you change any of them.

That will keep the binlogs around for longer.

Also, see if AWS has a different setting to allow for a longer "PITR" (Point In Time Recovery).

Since you have configured to keep 30 days' worth of binlogs (and assuming you can access them), the commandline `mysqlbinlog` with let you read those files and grep for the data you desire.  Good luck.

Comment: >'%expire_logs%'

Thanks, that doesn't answer my question - I'd like to analyze transactions in the past.


>AWS has a different setting to allow for a longer "PITR" (Point In Time Recovery).

I already have 30 days backup retention and there is no problem to restore. But I'd like to see transactions log in order to find when and how certain tables were modified. 
I restored a few PITR instances, but it's not practically and tricky to restore tens or hundreds instances - searching logs is much simplier.

Comment: @VitalyKarasikDevOps - I added a paragraph.